# Annoying message on teams that will pester me for 364 days and counting

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

We have a strange setup at work where we cannot automatically renew software.  We need to purchase it based on a yearly contract (every year we manually renew).  Don't ask me the reasons for this but here presents an annoying feature in Teams.

I purchased teams and after the trial I had to cancel it such that it would not auto renew.  The nice thing is since I purchased the yearly contract it allows me to keep using it until June 2019.  But since I cancelled it there is a message at the top that you cannot close out of or get rid of:

[image]

The message reads:

> This team has been cancelled and has 364 days remaining on the current contract.  Undo cancellation.

Come on already...first of all I would be okay if this message appeared say 30 days before ending my current contract.  I would also be ok such that this message and undoing cancellation was stored in the "Settings" page for teams (since there is one).  But don't put the message up from day one of the contract and keep it there where I cannot shut it off for 364 days!

Get rid of ASAP!

Comment: *Get rid of ASAP* ... yes, that would be welcomed by many dev-teams but unfortunately I think you missed an *it* there. Or do I get lectured again on the wonders of the English-American grammar ...

Comment: The get rid of asap is an inside joke :).  I have our end users tell me stuff like that on stuff that cannot be done as soon as possible.

Comment: Another inside joke is fixing this when you have 29 days left before cancellation :) I'm pretty sure they could make this dismissible, but that's a piece of code that has to suit a bunch of use cases, so you might  have to dismiss it once per month - would that be horribad on your end if that's the best they can do?

Comment: @TimPost - Let's put it this way - it would be better than what is there right now.  I guess the question is in this special case can we not just check the contract end date and if it is within 30 days show it else hide it?

Comment: It distracted me too. You can add this to a stylish sheet to hide it ASAP `.s-banner, .s-banner__warning {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: @JonH You might wanna censor your screencap a bit, one can see your full name and team name.

Comment: @Magisch All of that is derivable from the CV available through OPs profile, I'm sure they're not too concerned

Comment: Just ublock it.

Comment: Another special case to consider is the message to display when you have 6-8 weeks remaining on your contract.

Comment: @TimPost Probably a stretched solution, but we could imagine that a cancellation of a 12-months contract would convert it to two contracts: one 11-months free active contract + one 1-month paid renew-cancelled contract. This way it would only warn during the last month. Yet, it's still easier to add a compare rule like `if (duration_left > 31 days) skip_warning();`

Answer (score 4):

We've been around this a fair few times internally but we keep circling back to what seems to be the simplest possible solution; adapting cancellation as you suggest so that it isn't as invasive and functionally does what disabling auto-renewal would do.

So, as of today, if you cancel anywhere up to 14 days prior to your renewal the admins of your team won't see any banners until we get to within 14 days of the effective cancellation date (i.e. when your subscription was supposed to renew).

When cancelling we also give you the option of preventing new users from joining your team. If users leave or are removed from the team after cancellation, additional users may join, but only up to the number you had prior to cancellation. This stops you from being inadvertently billed more than you might expect when users join your team.

A snapshot of the UI:

[image: Cancellation UI]

And here's what a user sees if they try to join the team after users have been prevented from joining:

[image: Max Reached]

On the date that your subscription would be renewed it'll be cancelled and you'll get all the usual banners telling you that the team will be frozen after 14 days. You can re-activate your team via the billing screens:

[image: Re-activation]

Hope that helps a little!

Comment: I feel good about this change.  I'll take a SO hoodie please :).

Comment: @JonH contact me on dward@ and we'll get something arranged

Comment: sent you an email!

Answer (score -42):

## **The most common case**

Most people who cancel their team do so because they no longer want to use Teams. It's also likely that they're canceling it because they didn't achieve the engagement/adoption that they wanted. I emphasize this point because if someone cancels their Team and then truly continues to use it for 364 days, there actually is a really good case for continuing to remind them that it's going to disappear if they don't act. If they cancel it and stop using it - they'll never see the banner. Providing a message that is dismissable would ultimately probably just surprise them when it actually gets canceled months later. I don't think that's an ideal experience for the bulk of people that this feature targets

## **There are other drawbacks to canceling**

If you cancel an annual plan, while we might be pestering you with a banner, we *really* don't want you to get hit with more charges. That means, no new users can join during that entire year. So, whatever user count you have right now is static unless you un-cancel it. Therefore, I highly recommend not repurposing the cancelation feature as a way to prevent renewal, if at all possible.

## **I do see your point**

I do see your point about how some organizations might not allow auto-renewing solutions. I'll have to think about another solution here. Maybe there's a feature to be built that turns off auto-renew. But, to be completely honest, I don't think that the solution here will be to dampen the effects of the cancellation flow.

Comment: This completely misses the suggestion to notify for the last 30 days, or once a month, or some other reasonable amount of time. Leaving it up there for 364 days will just cause people to eventually ignore It, reducing the impact of the banner where it would actually be needed and actually detracting from the goal of the banner. High noise, low signal.

Comment: While I see your point, @TinyGiant, that makes the assumption that people who've canceled use the product daily for 364 days, which appears to not be the case in almost every scenario we've seen.

Comment: You've had the product out for what, two weeks? I hardly think that is enough time to be making sweeping generalizations about your demographic. In this case, and in pretty well any case where they cancel more than a month before the end of their plan and continue using it, this is a problem. Handwaving about how that isn't the primary use case isn't going to fix the problem.

Comment: Unless your argument is that you just dont care about the user experience of those who have cancelled, in which case i would remind you that, until the end of their contract, they are still a paying customer, regardless of whether they've cancelled or not.

Comment: @TinyGiant we've been testing the product with users for about 6 months now. We certainly are still observing a lot of data and this particular feature could be subject to change, but that wouldn't fix the problem that "cancelation" is a really bad proxy for "stop auto-renewing". We're talking about a separate feature. I must also note that I do feel a bit personally attacked by your assertion that I don't care about the user experience. That's an unnecessary attack.

Comment: Folks don't get mad I am just giving you the reality.  Chance in my case I am only cancelling due to the rules we have in place not to autorenew.  But even if I wasn't I cannot understand (since the customer paid already) why we dont leave the message off until it is close to actually renewing?  I dont get my comcast bill until its due within 2 weeks of due date, it doesnt remind me the day after I paid my previous one..

Comment: I'm sorry you feel that way. As for your controlled private testing, that doesn't really count towards real world usage all that much. I mean it does for the primary use case stuff and bugfinding, but in general you should expect real world users to be much more entertaining than beta testers. Especially stack overflow users.

Comment: I'm confused since the comment was deleted, what exactly was the point?  I cancelled to avoid auto renewal charges but I paid yearly and now you are telling me since I was originally given 10 users I can no longer add more?  This all doesn't really seem to make sense.  I should be able to add my limit (10 users) because I paid for it.  Why does it stop me from adding users?  This is bad design if you ask me.  So then I have to un cancel, add my users and re cancel?  Its kind of funny if you ask me...funny in a horrible now hellz no kind of way.

Comment: 30 days is not enough? I'm pretty sure if someone doesn't use a service for 30 days they *most likely* aren't interested in renewing it..

Comment: This is an amazingly terrible answer.... 1) You don't have a way to just pay for 1 year without auto renew. 2) you somehow decide that cancelling the auto renew has drawbacks such as not being able to add users *a full year before it expires* 3) You're advising against using the cancel subscription as a way to avoid auto renew when *you don't have any other way* to avoid auto renew ? I don't even use this product and this answer makes me never want to use it ....

Comment: @xyious I’m sorry that you feel that way. It’s a new product and not every feature is built on day 1. some great points have been raised in this discussion that I’m looking into, but that doesn’t mean we have every perfect answer right away. Though I don’t think your assessment of my answer being “amazingly terrible” is fair. Software development is an iterative process.

Comment: Your answer was *not* "we will fix this as soon as possible". As such your comment is fairly invalid. Your answer essentially was "please don't misuse cancel as a way to replace a feature that *does not exist*, as there are other drawbacks.... It's an amazingly terrible answer.

Comment: To expand on that: Your comment implies that your answer said "we will fix this as soon as possible". It did not. Your answer didn't even acknowledge that this *shouldn't* be the behavior.

Comment: @JonH quick update for you. After putting some thought towards it and chatting with the team, I don’t think changing cancelation is the solution to your problem. Providing more granular controls over renewal to be able to turn auto renewal off seems like the ideal scenario. Putting you in a pending cancellation state is not. I’m putting a spec together and circulating it internally - I’ll let you know as it progresses. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: Chance sounds good.

Comment: Why would you disallow new people joining the team after cancellation. The product is still valid as bought, and should function as bought until the end date.  If I cancel my subscription to my ISP, my isp doesn't say, well, you can only visit the sites you've visited up until now, but new sites you can only visit after resubscribing to our service. Who came up with that concept, because it's seriously flawed.

Comment: If this is left-as is it very well might be the first nail in this feature's unshipping container.

Comment: @Tschallacka That is because teams costs money per user per team, and more people inside the team means more money (and since the team is cancelled, there is no auto renew to get this new money for these new users (disclaimer: I'm just a normal SO user)

Comment: Then simply provide a creditcard screen, pay the extra fee for the new member to be added for the remaining year. It's not like license sales is rocket science. Being forced into an auto renew subscribtion is not a plus to consider teams.

Comment: I paid 120 bucks for it and it includes 10 users but I have only added 2 people so not allowing me to add the rest is what we are talking about Ferrybig - I am not trying to go over my max of 10.

Comment: @ChanceHeath - Is there any update on this?  I still despise this message and it is still there.  Can I please get rid of this message

Comment: @JonH sorry that this is still frustrating you. It has taken us longer to get to it than we anticipated, but we're on track to complete it by end of September.